# mail() not working correctly

Tags: php, email

I am trying to send out an email when a form is sent and nothing is happening.  I am using winHost as a provider.  I have tried making a seperate .php file to just test the mail() function but no cigar - 
    `mail('myemail','dfd','dsaf','dasfda');`

Here is my set up for mailing -

```
    $to = $agentemail;
$subject = "";
$message = "";
$from = "";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Please let me know if you need anymore info.

Comment: Do you have it configured correctly in your php.ini file?  Did you set it up from xampp or something similar?  Turn on error_reporting and see what errors return.

Comment: Your `from` header is empty...

Comment: Alfasin my header would be added by a value - $from;  romo how do I check to see?

Comment: You should make sure that your hosting provider allows mail(), and that you have it properly configured.

Comment: @Jaxkr It says SMTP with an email address.  I really don't know how to check.

Comment: @DavidBiga I'm saying this because of the warning in the "additional headers" section: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: @Alfasin what is my issue - it said if i leave it empty which it is not because $from has a value;

Comment: Also, it looks like you should use authentication: http://support.winhost.com/KB/a826/how-to-send-email-from-a-php-application.aspx and also here: http://support.winhost.com/KB/c237/configuring-smtp-authentication.aspx

Comment: @alfasin I still don't really understand.

Comment: Did you read links I posted ? If you didn't understand, and you want help, you should state what exactly didn't you understand.

Comment: Okay how do I create a email system with the php.ini

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @alfasin has pointed out, you need to follow the example code on the first link he gave to the [WinHost Knowledge Base](http://support.winhost.com/KB/a826/how-to-send-email-from-a-php-application.aspx):

You'll need to replace the host and username with details of an actual email account you've got setup.

```
<?php 
require_once "Mail.php"; 
$from = "Sender <postmaster@HostingAccountDomain.com>"; 
$to = "Recipient <user@HostingAccountDomain.com>"; 
$subject = "This is a test email sent via php"; 
$body = "This is a test email"; 

$host = "mail.HostingAccountDomain.com"; 
$username = "postmaster@HostingAccountDomain.com"; 
$password = "email_password"; 

$headers = array ('From' => $from, 
                  'To' => $to, 
                  'Subject' => $subject); 

$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', 
                      array ('host' => $host, 
                             'auth' => true, 
                             'username' => $username, 
                             'password' => $password)
                      ); 
$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body); 
?>
```